# How to pick a random no from a list (contain 1 to n values) with certain thresold value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I have a list like the below:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
thresold value = 0.5
```

From this list I want to pick a random number which is above the thresold value (in this case 0.5).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `list comprehension` to filter it and then `random.choice()` to get a random one. See below...

```
import random
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
threshold_value = 4
r = random.choice([x for x in l if x>threshold_value])
print(r)
```